# Trouble following proof of Rule of Iterated Expectations

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, expectation, conditional-expectation

My text has the following definition of expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \int x dF(x) = \begin{cases}
\sum_x xf(x) & \text{ if X is discrete } \\
\int xf(x)dx & \text{ if X is continuous }
\end{cases}
$$

And conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y) = \begin{cases}
\sum xf_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)dx & \text{ discrete case } \\
\int xf_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)dx & \text{ continuous case }
\end{cases}$$

Then it tries to show that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \mathbb{E}(Y)$ with this proof, saying that "We'll prove the first equation. Using the definition of conditional expectation and the fact that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)f_X(x)$.":

$$1.\ \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \int \mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x)f_X(x)dx$$

$$2.\ \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \int\int yf(y\mid x)dyf(x)dx$$

$$3.\ \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \int\int yf(y\mid x)f(x)dxdy$$

$$3.\ \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \int\int yf(x,y)dxdy$$

I don't understand step #1. I *do* understand the idea that $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y)$ is a particular value while $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y)$ is a random variable that takes on those values. But here's how I imagine doing the proof:

Let $Z = \mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)$. Then:

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \mathbb{E}(Z) = \int zf_z(z)$$

But then you're stuck getting from here to step 1. I can hand wave a little bit and say that since $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)$ takes on specific values $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x)$, and the definition of expectation is having you integrate over all the possible values for your variable that $z = \mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x)$. Then we have:

$$\int zf_z(z) = \int \mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x) f_Z(z)dz$$

But then we somehow still need to justify substituting in $f_X(x)dx$ for $f_Z(z)dz$, and I don't feel totally comfortable that either of these moves is allowed.

Comment: Would you say the same if it were $X^2$ instead of $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$? If not, where do you see a difference? They're both random variables whose value you know if you know the value of $X$, so you need to integrate them with the density for $X$.

Comment: I would like give you a warning: this book is not a respectable one. Not every continuous distribution has a density function.

Comment: If it helps, consider the function $g(y)=E(X|Y=y)$ and the definition of $E(g(Y))$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what book do you consider respectable?

Comment: @joriki: I would say based on the formula the expectation for a random variable uses the density for that random variable. So for $X^2$ I'd think we'd use the density function for $X^2$, not the one for $X$.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Hav e you studied some measure theory? Modern probability theory cannot be studied without measure theory. There are a few books that develop measure theory and probability theory simultaneously. One such book is the one by Billingsley.